# Load Properties into an InputStream

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a method that takes an InputStream as a parameter. The method extracts Properties from the InputStream and returns the "version" property. This property holds the version of the application.

```
public String getVersion(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(inputStream);
    String version = properties.getProperty("version");
    return version;
}
```

For testing purposes, I'd like to create a Properties object, set some properties, and then load the properties into an InputStream. Finally, the InputStream would be passed to the method under test.

```
@Test
public void testGetAppVersion() {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("version", "1.0.0.test");

    // Load properties into InputStream
}
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `store` method to write the properties to a stream.

Here's an example that uses byte array streams:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("version", "1.0.0.test");

ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
props.store(os, "comments");

InputStream s = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());

String version = getVersion(s);
```

But I believe the following way is simpler (input stream from string *file content*):

```
InputStream is = 
    new ByteArrayInputStream("version=1.0.0.test\n".getBytes());
```